# SwiftUI: Displaying the navigation bar using NavigationStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I want to display a navigation bar having an orange background color and a title with white color.

Everything works fine with this setup:

```
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.white)]
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .orange
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
```

And the source code for my screen looks like this:

```
struct ScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Row", destination: Text("Tapped on row"))
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("List")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

If I replace the NavigationView with a NavigationStack, the navigation bar disappears.

Is there something that I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to apply your `.navigationTitle()` modifier to views that are inside of `NavigationStack`:

```
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Row", destination: Text("Tapped on row"))
        }
        .navigationTitle("List")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
```

That seems to fix that problem.

Answer (score 5):

Using SwiftUI only and NavigationStack, you can achieve a white title text on an orange background,
with this code.

```
struct ScreenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(0..<50, id: \.self) { _ in
                NavigationLink("Row", destination: Text("Tapped on row"))
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) { Text("List").foregroundColor(.white) }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(Color.orange, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScreenView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer!
If I scroll down the list, that orange background is expanding and it's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: If I scroll down the list, that orange background is **not** expanding as you mentioned.
 I have updated my answer to show that the `orange` background does not expand
 when you scroll down the list.

Comment: now it works as expected. Thank you for updating your answer!